# .net core the target process exited without triggering an event initiated by CoreCLR

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2

I am using .net core 2.2 and when I run the project I get the following error:

The target process exited without triggering an event fired by CoreCLR. Make sure the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This is to be expected if the target process is not running on .NET Core.
The program '[12020] dotnet.exe' exited with code 2147516566 (0x80008096).

I couldn't find the source of the problem, can you help me?

Comment: Do you have .NET Core 2.2 runtime installed? Other than that, we can't help since you haven't shown us any details.

Comment: Yes installed. The project was working and after turning the computer off and on, it stopped working.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you run the project inside the VS or else? Besides, I suggest you could use  the new version of the .net core since the 2.2 is out of support from MSFT now.

Comment: I'm trying to run an old project. I'm trying to run it with IIS Express. It's made with layered architecture and it works in Angular.

Comment: Run it through VS. Visual studio is going to create a terminal window, that terminal window is going to have more information. For me it was that .NET Core 2.2 Runtime (v2.2.8) was not installed. I installed v2.2.0 but apparently it needed 2.2.8. Or maybe I used the wrong install page.